# How can I solve the type of an Array in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
private validatorsFormAllField(FormGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(FormGroup.controls).forEach((field) => {
        const control = FormGroup.get(field);
        if (control instanceof FormControl) {
            control.markAsDirty({ onlySelf: true });
        } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
            this.validatorsFormAllField(control as FormGroup);
        }
    });
}
```

I get an error when checking `instanceof` the `FormGroup` with a type

> The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.

Also the autocomplete isn't registering the type of the `FormGroup` in the else if-block so I assume I can't check the `FormGroup` type like this.

What is the proper way to determine what the type of array being passed is?

Comment: Can you show the what `get` function of `FormGroups` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormGroup: FormGroup` has the effect of "create a variable named `FormGroup`, of type `FormGroup`, and, since the variable is called `FormGroup`, for the rest of this function, `FormGroup` refers to a variable, not a type."  (In technical terms, you've [shadowed or masked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your type.)

Try something like `formGroup: FormGroup` instead. (Using camelCase for variable names is a more common JavaScript/TypeScript coding style, and it should avoid this problem.)